# how to get the To, BCC, CC Email address instead of Display names?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, outlook, outlook-addin

I am able to get the To, BCC, CC, Subject, Body on Item send event but my problem is I am getting the display names instead of Email addresses

```
   MailItem outlookMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)Item;
   outlookPropertites.ToAddress = outlookMailItem.To;
```

this is returning me the display name but I want the email addresses. Is there any other property to get the email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection, for each Recipient check the `Type` (olTo/olCC/OlBCC), `Name`, and `Address` properties.